# How can i upload preview images?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, upload

In my HTML form I have input filed with type file.
for example :

```
<input name="txt_file" type="file" id="txt_file" multiple>
```

I use code in this link here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/L45LW/5/

How can i upload all image with javascript?

I want to store images info into array to send other page with POST in javascript.

Please help me

Comment: What do you mean by "preview div with javascript"?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. I can see all the thumbs of the images I want to upload. Maybe you need better explain what the problem is and what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes that works. how can i upload all selected files? user can multiple select files

Comment: it does show all the files. What is the problem here?

Comment: I want upload all files when submit form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very clear what are you asking for! But at least you should have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `form` tag to upload files.

```
 <form id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="txt_file" type="file" id="txt_file" multiple/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. My code show preview images just. I want to upload all files in div when submit form not just current files in input field